# bootstrap 3 and a list that has 2 buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap.  I'm using jsrender and what i'm looking for is a way to display a listing that has the text(where if you click anywhere in like say a col-lg-9) on the left side it takes you to one place and an btn type on the right that would take you to another.

I've tried using a list-group-item

```
 {{for d }}
     <dl class="list-group-item">
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
             <a href="PeopleAddEdit.aspx?ID={{:PeopleID}}" class="btn btn-default">
                 <dt>{{: FirstName}} {{: LastName}}</dt>
                                 </a>
             <a href="PeopleDelete.aspx?ID={{:PeopleID}}" class="btn btn-default">delete</a>
         </div>
     </dl>
    {{/for}}
```

I've also tried media-list

```
     {{for d }}
     <ul class="media-list">
         <li class="media">
             <a href="PeopleAddEdit.aspx?ID={{:PeopleID}}" class="media-body">
                 <h4>{{: FirstName}} {{: LastName}}</h4>
                               </a>
             <a href="PeopleDelete.aspx?ID={{:PeopleID}}" class="pull-right"><span class="media-object">delete</span></a>
         </li>
     </ul>
    {{/for}}
```

I'm just not getting it.  I also tried using horizontal buttons but that didn't get me there either.

what would be the proper way to do this.  I'm not asking for code right now.. just to the right tree to bark up.

so I would like to learn how to make something that looks kind of like this.. course there will be more than one row.

[image]

Thanks
Shannon

edit.  I'm not sure if this is the way it should be done.. but I think this gets me closer.  Putting it out there for others.

```
 <ul class="media-list">
        <li class="media">

            <div class="media-body">
                <a href="#1">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading 1</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-right">
                <a href="#2">
                    <%--<img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64">--%>
                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media">
           <div class="media-body">
                <a href="#3">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading 1</h4>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-right">
                <a href="#4">
                    <%--<img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64">--%>
                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I used the VS 2013 extension called Bootstrap Snippet Pack.  It helped me with the a place to start code wise.  I understand that those not new to bootstrap might find that a bit elementary but for me it seemed to help.

edit --
I'm still trying to figure out how to make the anchor so that I can click anywhere and have the link fire off.. right now it will only fire if I am over the text...  So that is what i'm waiting on before I mark this as answered.
thanks

Comment: So are you still seeking alternative solutions? If not, please create an answer and accept it. If so, update your question with the remaining issues.